# Invoke verb on multiple files via Shell.Application

Tags: powershell, com, windows-shell

I'm using "Shell.Application" COM object for some automation via PowerShell and I'm stuck on situation where I need to invoke verb on multiple items in folder. Basically I need to simulate situation where user selects multiple files/folders and calls verb from shell menu.

I can do it without any problem on single item, but I haven't found method how to call it on multiple items. Any idea how to do it?

**Edit:**
This is how I call it on single item:

```
$shell = New-Object -Com "Shell.Application"
$shell.Namespace($Path).Self.InvokeVerb("some action")
```

Comment: Please provide code for the single item that you have tried

Comment: From looking at the available interfaces there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. There would need to be a way to create your own collection of items and it doesn't look like there's a method for that. About all I can think of is a kludge that involves creating shortcuts for the desired items in a temporary folder and then calling `InvokeVerb` on the that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`InvokeVerbEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to execute on all files in a folder:

```
$shell.Namespace("C:\test").Items().InvokeVerbEx()
```

For particular files in a folder, I would think the best way is to put the single item code that you have in a loop:

```
$path1, $path2 | %{ $shell.Namespace($_).Self.InvokeVerb() }
```

The [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method may be of use too

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, the Filter method looks like the right way (I can't use you ForEach example since it behaves as if you would call it once on each item). However there's a problem that it accepts only simple wildcard filter and I need to specify full file/folder names. Any other idea?

Comment: Items().InvokeVerbEx() only works for one file type (only for exe, txt and so on). After executing one type, such as exe, the execution of Items().InvokeVerbEx() stops.

Comment: The Filter method is awesome. It works.